# The second HTTP POST REST call to a Play 2.5 app's web service returns a 403 response

Tags: scala, https, playframework, twilio

I have a Play 2.5 application with forms, comet, Silhouette auth, and a variety of REST API calls. I have some WS actions that are intercepted to return 403 responses *the second time* they are called.

The app's WS actions include a JSON POST, some Twilio Callbacks (mostly GETs + one POST), and a Google Dialogflow fulfilment webhook (POST).

When I run in Dev mode with requests proxied to my application all of the APIs and callbacks work fine through multiple calls. I test this config's callbacks and web UI with Ngrok:443 -> localhost:9000

When I run in Prod mode traffic traverses Cloudflare -> Nginx:443 -> localhost:9000.  One of my Twilio callbacks (a text receive POST) and my Google Dialogflow webhook WS (also a POST) return 403 *the second time and every subsequent time they are called*. The first call succeeds with 200 status, then for a day or for a few hours they only return 403.

The strange thing is that my Twilio callbacks that are in response to my Twilio API calls, all function fine. My regular JSON call (POST) works fine too.

If I go to the Twilio console I can replay the failed POSTs and every one of them can call my app's POST endpoint with a 200 response.

I'm baffled why some POSTs are impacted and not others. Is this likely to be a subtle CSRF condition?

This is the Twilio SMS receive callback:

```
def twilioSMSIncoming = Action.async {
  implicit request =>
  val isValid = twilioUtils.validate(request.uri, request.body.asFormUrlEncoded, request.headers.get("x-twilio-signature"))
  Logger.debug(s"Request validity: ${isValid}")
  if (!isValid)
    Future(Unauthorized)

  request.body.asFormUrlEncoded match {
    case Some(reqMap) => {
      val reqStrStrMap = twilioUtils.paramSeq2FirstParams(reqMap)
      // Process some state and Return an SMS </Response>...</Response>
      Future(Ok(smsAction(reqStrStrMap)))
    }
    case None => {
      Logger.info("No asFormUrlEncoded content")
      Future(BadRequest)
    }
  }
}
```

No application code returns 403 responses (though the underlying framework can).

This is the Nginx log for two text messages just now:

```
172.69.62.7 - - [19/Mar/2018:07:24:03 +1100] "POST /twilio/smsincoming HTTP/1.1" 200 195 "-" "TwilioProxy/1.1"
162.158.78.229 - - [19/Mar/2018:07:24:12 +1100] "POST /twilio/smsincoming HTTP/1.1" 403 2111 "-" "TwilioProxy/1.1"
```

That second IP makes me suspicious it's a header from CloudFlare...

This is the Twilio console info:

Url:

```
https://ringrosie.com/twilio/smsincoming
```

Parameters

```
ApiVersion=2010-04-01&SmsSid=SMe290274cf5d34d5061525107a6e5e5b7&SmsStatus=received&SmsMessageSid=SMe290274cf5d34d5061525107a6e5e5b7&NumSegments=1&From=%2B61407703662&ToState=&MessageSid=SMe290274cf5d34d5061525107a6e5e5b7&AccountSid=AC24dfcd5db910071156acb9747ae18bcf&ToZip=&FromCountry=AU&ToCity=&FromCity=&To=%2B61437825889&FromZip=&Body=Test&ToCountry=AU&FromState=&NumMedia=0
```

Message Text:

```
Msg=Forbidden&sourceComponent=14100&ErrorCode=11200&EmailNotification=false&httpResponse=403&LogLevel=ERROR&url=https%3A%2F%2Fringrosie.com%2Ftwilio%2Fsmsincoming
```

Response Headers:

```
Transfer-Encoding chunked
X-Cache MISS from ip-172-18-0-178
CF-RAY 3fda6bdf9a3f5741-IAD
Server cloudflare
X-Cache-Lookup MISS from ip-172-18-0-178:3128
Set-Cookie PLAY_SESSION=; Max-Age=-86400; Expires=Sat, 17 Mar 2018 20:24:12 GMT; Path=/; HTTPOnly
Date Sun, 18 Mar 2018 20:24:12 GMT
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8
Expect-CT max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
```

Body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Unauthorized</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAlFJREFUeNqUU8tOFEEUPVVdNV3dPe8xYRBnjGhmBgKjKzCIiQvBoIaNbly5Z+PSv3Aj7DSiP2B0rwkLGVdGgxITSCRIJGSMEQWZR3eVt5sEFBgTb/dN1yvnnHtPNTPG4PqdHgCMXnPRSZrpSuH8vUJu4DE4rYHDGAZDX62BZttHqTiIayM3gGiXQsgYLEvATaqxU+dy1U13YXapXptpNHY8iwn8KyIAzm1KBdtRZWErpI5lEWTXp5Z/vHpZ3/wyKKwYGGOdAYwR0EZwoezTYApBEIObyELl/aE1/83cp40Pt5mxqCKrE4Ck+mVWKKcI5tA8BLEhRBKJLjez6a7MLq7XZtp+yyOawwCBtkiBVZDKzRk4NN7NQBMYPHiZDFhXY+p9ff7F961vVcnl4R5I2ykJ5XFN7Ab7Gc61VoipNBKF+PDyztu5lfrSLT/wIwCxq0CAGtXHZTzqR2jtwQiXONma6hHpj9sLT7YaPxfTXuZdBGA02Wi7FS48YiTfj+i2NhqtdhP5RC8mh2/Op7y0v6eAcWVLFT8D7kWX5S9mepp+C450MV6aWL1cGnvkxbwHtLW2B9AOkLeUd9KEDuh9fl/7CEj7YH5g+3r/lWfF9In7tPz6T4IIwBJOr1SJyIGQMZQbsh5P9uBq5VJtqHh2mo49pdw5WFoEwKWqWHacaWOjQXWGcifKo6vj5RGS6zykI587XeUIQDqJSmAp+lE4qt19W5P9o8+Lma5DcjsC8JiT607lMVkdqQ0Vyh3lHhmh52tfNy78ajXv0rgYzv8nfwswANuk+7sD/Q0aAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
        <style>
        html, body, pre {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Monaco, 'Lucida Console', monospace;
            background: #ECECEC;
        }
        h1 {
            margin: 0;
            background: #333;
            padding: 20px 45px;
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
            border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
            font-size: 28px;
        }
        p#detail {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 15px 45px;
            background: #888;
            border-top: 4px solid #666;
            color: #111;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3);
            font-size: 14px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Unauthorized</h1>
        <p id="detail">
        You must be authenticated to access this page.
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And, of course, when I replay this transaction from the Twilio console debugger it succeeds:

```
162.158.78.85 - - [19/Mar/2018:07:41:41 +1100] "POST /twilio/smsincoming HTTP/1.1" 200 195 "-" "TwilioProxy/1.1"
```

**Update** I removed Cloudflare so my Prod environment is just Nginx:443 -> localhost:9000 and I'm still getting 403s. This is the header from the Twilio console now:

```
X-Cache MISS from ip-172-18-19-175
Server nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
X-Cache-Lookup MISS from ip-172-18-19-175:3128
Set-Cookie PLAY_SESSION=; Max-Age=-86400; Expires=Sat,     17 Mar 2018 21:25:46 GMT; Path=/; HTTPOnly
Content-Length 2111
Date Sun, 18 Mar 2018 21:25:46 GMT
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Do you have any logs from your application when it returns those 403 ?
Could you also share the code of one of these endpoints ?

Comment: I've added some logging and the Twilio SMS endpoint, which extends BasicController (non-Silhouette).

Comment: Did you try removing the play http filters ? Like you said it might be a csrf issue. But it's weird that the call works from the twilio console and from the api. Did you put the play logs in a debug mode ?

Comment: Thanks @vdebergue for pushing me in this direction. It does seem to be CSRF related. I turned up play.filters logging to trace then configured the application.conf CSRF section to ignore CSRF when a header called X-Twilio-Signature is present and now I can reliably receive endpoint calls about incoming SMS. Now I need to figure out what the syntax is to add something like Google-Actions-API-Version to the ignore list so I can get Google callbacks working.

Comment: Webhook requests are inherently cross site requests, so CSRF filtering shouldn't be applied to those endpoints. You need to validate the request another way. You're already validating the Twilio request using the `X-Twilio-Signature` header. The ways to [validate the Dialogflow request are either HTTP basic auth or by setting your own custom header](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/webhook).

Comment: Thanks @philnash. I did end up using the custom header for bypassing CSRF filtering of Dialogflow webhooks and using basic auth. I can't fathom why I was getting away without excluding them from CSRF filtering.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird it worked the first time! Glad you're sorted now.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to add header matches for the headers I knew would be present in the Twilio and Google actions API calls to the CSRF configuration in application.conf according to the Play 2.5 documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCsrf

```
csrf {
  # Sets the cookie to be sent only over HTTPS
  #cookie.secure = true
  header {
    bypassHeaders {
      X-Twilio-Signature = "*"
      X-Google-Home-Call = "*"
    }
  }
}
```

NB: Twilio's header is in all Twilio calls, but the Google DialogFlow is custom. DialogFlow lets you configure a custom header in the webhook specification.

Play 2.6's CSRF exemption routes annotations would be a better solution, but for now I have 2.5 working.

I'm still not sure why the second and subsequent calls were failing after the initial call succeeded.